# kotlin, how to escape a string for putting in a json string

Tags: json, kotlin

Receiving some string and when put in to json string it is invalid and need to be escaped.

Is there a build in function for escape a string in kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.json.JSONObject
val jsonString = """{"id": "1234", "name": "John\"Doe"}"""
val escapedString = JSONObject.quote(jsonString)
println(escapedString)
```